# Frequency determination from Dimension analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

the time averaged total energy, $\bar E$,
has the following $\varepsilon$ expansion in $D$ dimension:
\begin{equation}
\bar{E}=\varepsilon^{2-D}\frac{E_0}{2\lambda}+ \varepsilon^{4-D}E_1
\end{equation}
 from the above equation how can we write 
\begin{equation}
\omega_{\rm m}^2=
1-\frac{1}{2\lambda}\frac{(D-2)E_0}{(4-D)E_1}\,.
\end{equation}
where $$\omega_{\rm m}^2=1-\varepsilon_{\rm m}^2,$$  and $\lambda$ is a constant factor.
m denotes that angular frequency $\omega $ is minimum.

> Can someone explain me how equation (2) can be written from equation
>   (1)
>   If you feel problem or need more information then please comment. 
>   thanks in advance.
>   for more info see [here in equation (39 and 40)](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525)

Comment: Derivation:) $\frac{\partial}{\partial \varepsilon}$ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explaining Antoine's suggestion:

Differentiate $\bar E$ with respect to $\epsilon$ to find its optimal value. You get
$(2-D)\epsilon^{1-D} E_0/(2\lambda)+(4-D)\epsilon^{3-D}E_1=0$. Factor $\epsilon^{1-D}$ from that to get
$(2-D)E_0/2\lambda+(4-D)\epsilon^2E_1=0$. Now solve for $\epsilon^2$ to get $\epsilon^2=-E_0/2\lambda E_1(2-D)/(4-D)$. Then $1-\epsilon^2=1+E_0/2\lambda E_1(2-D)/(4-D)$ which is ame as your final answer.