# Yang–Mills theory

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

We define the energy as
$$E = I_F + I_K + I_V,$$
where,
$$I_F [A]= \frac{1}{2} \int d^Dx \operatorname{tr} F^2_{ij},$$
$F_{ij}$ represents the electromagnetic force.
$$I_K [\phi,A]= \frac{1}{2} \int d^Dx (D_j \phi)^\dagger (D_j \phi),$$
$$I_V [\phi]= \int d^Dx V(\phi),$$
Given a solution $\bar \phi(x)$, $\bar A_j(x)$, we define scaled fields
$$f_\lambda(x)= \bar\phi(\lambda x),$$
$$g_{j\lambda}(x)= \lambda \bar A_j(\lambda x).$$
Proceeding as in the pure scalar case, we find that
\begin{align}
 E(\lambda) &= I_F [g_\lambda ] + I_K [f_\lambda , g_\lambda ] + I_V [f_\lambda ] \\
 & = \lambda^{4-D} I_F [\bar A] +  \lambda^{2-D} I_K [\bar \phi,\bar A]+  \lambda^{-D} I_V [\bar \phi] \tag{1}
\end{align}
which is stationary at $\lambda = 1$ if

> **I just don't understand how $$I_F [A]=\lambda^{4-D} I_F [\bar A],$$ is in the equation (1)**

[The post is slightly related with this: link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398928/dimensions-analysis-in-differential-equation)

Comment: *Yang*-Mills theory?

Comment: sorry my bad , yup.

Comment: I do not understand a thing: if $I_F[g_\lambda]=\int d^Dx tr F^2(g_\lambda)$, with $F_{ij}(g_\lambda)(x)=\partial_i \lambda \bar{A}_j(\lambda x)-\partial_j \lambda \bar{A}_i(\lambda x)$, then in $tr F^2$ I can extract immediatly 2 powers of $\lambda$ and with the change of variables $\lambda x=y$ we get $-D$ powers, and so $2-D$ in total. Did I misunderstand your notation?

Comment: @Avitus: Did you take into account the derivatives? You should be able to extract 4 powers of $\lambda$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov you are right; now I see it. I messed up with notation :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So,

$$F_{ij}(g_\lambda)(x)=\frac{\partial \lambda \bar{A}_j(\lambda x)}{\partial x_i} -\frac{\partial \lambda \bar{A}_i(\lambda x)}{\partial x_j}$$

becomes with the change of variables $y=\lambda x$

$$F_{ij}(g_\lambda)(x)=\frac{\partial \lambda^2 \bar{A}_j(\lambda x)}{\partial \lambda x_i} -\frac{\partial \lambda^2 \bar{A}_i(\lambda x)}{\partial \lambda x_j} = \lambda^2 \left(\frac{\partial\bar{A}_j(y)}{\partial y_i} -\frac{\partial \bar{A}_i(y)}{\partial y_j}\right)$$

which implies that

$$I_F[g_\lambda]=\int d^Dx \; \mbox{tr } F^2(g_\lambda) = \lambda^{4-D}\int d^Dy \; \mbox{tr } F^2(A) \; .$$

Comment: Can you check this question please? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476497/derricks-theorem-for-d-2-and-3