# Derricks Theorem for D= 2 and 3

Tags: real-analysis, dimension-theory-analysis, nonlinear-system

According to Derrick's theorem we can write \begin{align}
E &= \frac{1}{2} \int d^Dx  \frac{1}{\lambda^2}\left( \nabla \phi_i (\frac{x}{\lambda})\right)^2 + \int d^Dx V(\phi_i(\frac{x}{\lambda})),\\
&=\lambda^{D-2} I_K +\lambda^{D} I_V. \tag{1}
\end{align}
 $\lambda = 1$ must be a stationary point of $E(\lambda)$, which implies that,
\begin{equation} 
 0=(D-2) I_K[\bar\phi]+D I_V[\bar\phi].
\end{equation}
I don't understand is

> For $D \geq 3$, ($1$) can only be satisfied if both $I_K$
>   and $I_V$ vanish, which rules out anything but a constant vacuum
>   solution.

Can you elaborate this please.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62858/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/243729/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the origin of all the terms, but I think what's happening is that both $I_K$ and $I_V$ are positive. This means that for the expression

$$\begin{equation} 
 0=(D-2) I_K[\bar\phi]+D I_V[\bar\phi].
\end{equation}$$

to work out, $D-2$ has to be negative. If $D-2>0$, then you'll only get zero if both $I_K$ and $I_V$ are zero.

Comment: in one line you are saying that, $D-2$ has to be negative ans then then you say $D−2>0$. Can you write a bit please.

Comment: If you want an interesting solution beside the trivial one $D-2\leq 0$, because if $D-2>0$ you can easily see that you only have a solution for $I_K=I_V=0$.